# Example for activity that starts another activity but is still visible

Tags: android

I just read the following from Android Developers docs:

> Here's the order of operations that occur when Activity A starts
>   Activity B:
>
> 1. Activity A's onPause() method executes.
> 2. Activity B's onCreate(), onStart(), and onResume() methods execute in sequence. (Activity B now has user focus.)
> 3. Then, if Activity A is no longer visible on screen,
>      its onStop() method executes.

I just want to know when an activity can start another and still be visible(a concrete example). (because it means that `onStop()` is always calls when I switch activities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start an Activity B like a dialog if you specify a flag in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityB"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"/>
```

Then Activity B will not take the full screen and you will still see the underlying activity.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that an activity can act as a dialog, I will choose this answer (need to wait at least 10 minuets)

Answer (score 1):

`onStop()` won't be called if you previous activity is `visible` to user.

`onStop` will be called only after previous activity is `completely invisible` to user.

So if new `activity` is `dialog` or some `transparent` background, then previous activity will be displayed to user and `onStop()` of previous activity won't be called.